# Accessing and adding on an array of structures

Tags: assembly, x86, structure

I'm trying to access my array of structures, it doesn't seem to be working well, here's my code for trying to search the array of structures based on the string 'firstname'.

```
    menu db 10, '------MENU------', 10, '1. Add Student', 10, '2. Delete Student', 10, '3. Delete All', 10, '4. Search Student', 10, '5. Display All', 10, '6. Exit', 10 
menulen equ $-menu
namep db 'Enter name: '
nameplen equ $-namep
fnamep db 'Enter firstname: '
fnameplen equ $-fnamep
lnamep db 'Enter lastname: '
lnameplen equ $-lnamep
agep db 'Enter age: '
ageplen equ $-agep
unitsp db 'Enter units enrolled: '
unitsplen equ $-unitsp
fullp db 'Sorry, the record is already full.', 10
fullplen equ $-fullp
record db '----Student Record----', 10
recordlen equ $-record
deleteallp db '----Deleted all Record----', 10
deleteallplen equ $-deleteallp
deleteerrorp db '----Student not in the record----', 10
deleteerrorplen equ $-deleteerrorp
delete db 'Deleted ', 10
deletelen equ $-delete
space db ' '
spacelen equ $-space
newline db '', 10
newlinelen equ $-newline
printfname db 'First name: '
printfnamelen equ $-printfname
printlname db 'Last name: '
printlnamelen equ $-printlname
printage db 'Age: '
printagelen equ $-printage
printunits db 'Number of units enrolled: '
printunitslen equ $-printunits
student equ 88
firstname equ 0
lastname equ 40
age equ 80
units equ 84
array_size equ 5


choice resb 1
x resb array_size*student
size resb 1
temp resb 1
string resb 40

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, namep
    mov edx, nameplen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 3
    mov edx, 0
    mov ecx, string
    mov edx, 80
    int 80h

    mov byte[temp], 0

    getstudentloop:
        mov al, byte[size]
        cmp byte[temp], al
        je studentnotfound

        mov esi, string
        mov ecx,esi
        imul ecx,[temp]
        mov edi, [ecx+x+student+firstname]

        cld 
        repe cmpsb
        dec esi
        dec edi

        jz studentdelete

        inc byte[temp]
        jmp getstudentloop

    studentdelete:
        mov ecx,esi
        imul ecx,[temp]
        mov word[ecx+x+student+firstname], 0

        mov ecx,esi
        imul ecx,[temp]
        mov word[ecx+x+student+lastname], 0

        mov ecx,esi
        imul ecx,[temp]
        mov word[ecx+x+student+age], 0

        mov ecx,esi
        imul ecx,[temp]
        mov word[ecx+x+student+units], 0

        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, delete
        mov edx, deletelen
        int 80h

        dec byte[size]

        jmp menustart
    studentnotfound:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, deleteerrorp
        mov edx, deleteerrorplen
        int 80h

        jmp menustart
```

I'm not able to get the string firstname, so when I compare, it fails. 
I'm also not sure how to add to my array of structures, because it keeps overwriting the ones that I've added earlier, turning the whole array the element that I last added. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

```
    cmp byte[size], 5
    jge full

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, fnamep
    mov edx, fnameplen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx,esi
    imul ecx,[size]                  
    lea ecx,[ecx+x+student+firstname]
    mov edx, 20
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, lnamep
    mov edx, lnameplen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx,esi
    imul ecx,[size]                  
    lea ecx,[ecx+x+student+lastname]
    mov edx, 20
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, agep
    mov edx, ageplen
    int 80h


    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx,esi
    imul ecx,[size]                    
    lea ecx,[ecx+x+student+age]
    mov edx, 3
    int 80h


    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, unitsp
    mov edx, unitsplen
    int 80h


    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx,esi
    imul ecx,[size]                  
    lea ecx,[ecx+x+student+units]
    mov edx, 3
    int 80h


    add byte[size], 1
    jmp menustart
```

Comment: In your very first sys_read, you set `edx` twice, and `ebx` not at all. I don't think that's your problem, but you might want to fix it anyway...

Comment: You haven't even shown us what the structure is like, and the code is missing parts so we can't compile and try it. Use a debugger and see where your program is doing something you didn't intend. Also, comment your code if you want other people to help.

Comment: I've fixed it now, the only part that I'm having trouble now, is putting the variable into edi, for comparing purposes. 

       mov ecx,student
       imul ecx,[temp]
       mov edi, [x+ecx+firstname]

Answer (score 0):

a. You forgot to initialize SIZE! You only defined it...

b. You have defined SIZE and TEMP to be bytes.

```
size resb 1
temp resb 1
```

But the following code expects a double word. This is a requirement of the IMUL instruction when a memory operand is involved!

```
imul ecx,[temp]
imul ecx,[size]
```

So simply write

```
size resd 1
temp resd 1

mov dword[size], 0
mov dword[temp], 0
```